# Is only one factory implied or there may be a number of them when we say "a factory closure" or "factory closures"?

Tags: singular-vs-plural, attributive-nouns

As far as I understand, when a noun is used attributively we can't say whether it's only one or it implies some number of itself.
To check my supposition, I made up some collocations.

---

Am I right that:

**(1)** *a factory closure*
can mean
**(1a)** *the closure of a factory*
or
**(1b)** *the closure of factories*

---

Am I right that:

**(2)** *factory closures*
can mean
**(2a)** *the closures of a factory*
or
**(2b)** *the closures of factories*

---

I was told "(2a) doesn't really make sense".
So I wrote a context, which, as it seems to me, is appropriate for (2a):
First owner of a factory got broke. He closed it. Then he sold it to another person which opened it but after a while he also got broke and closed the factory again.

Comment: Because you included the indefinite article, your #1 ***a** factory closure* can *only* refer to a single closure. Without that, in some contexts the *actual* noun phrase here could refer "generically, in the abstract" to potentially multiple closures. For example, *In this time of economic uncertainty, **factory closure** is a matter of genuine concern for workers in our county*. Note that your #2a doesn't really make sense. You can only normally close one factory once.

Comment: Because ***factory closure*** is a rather "abstract" noun, it might be easier to examine the relevant syntax by looking at a more common "attributive noun" usage, such as ***car radio***. For which the plural is ***car radios*** (***cars radio*** and ***cars radios*** are syntactic nonsense).

Comment: Whilst, as FumbleFingers says, there are exceptions based on context, if *factory* is single then it can safely be assumed that one factory is being closed. if plural forms, *factories* and *closures* then it is more than one.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I've added a context for (2a) at the bottom of the original post. Is it appropriate?

Comment: Is there any good reason to be investigating the semantics / syntax of attributive noun usages using such an "awkward" example? Why not ***car radio**?*

Comment: He **went broke**, he didn't "got broke".

Comment: @FumbleFingers If I, by analogy with this thread, create a new one where I will ask "_Am I right that "a car radio" can mean both "the radio for a car" and "the radio for cars"_?", then I will be told that there isn't a difference between "the radio for a car" and "the radio for cars". That is, "_a car radio_" is more inappropriate variant than "_a factory closure_".

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. ***A car radio*** is unexceptional, as is the plural ***car radios***. But I struggle to imagine any context  where someone would refer to ***the radio for a car*** or ***the radio for cars*** (even though both are syntactically valid sequences).

Comment: It is possible to dream up plausible scenarios where ***the* closures of *the* factory** makes sense (e.g. the factory had to shut its doors several times in recent memory because of raw material shortages  -- though **the recurring closures of the factory** would be better) but I struggle to come up with a scenario where ***the* closures of *a* factory**  would be idiomatic.

Answer (score 0):

When you say 'factory closures', the noun 'factory' is acting as an adjective to describe the 'closures', so you have a *noun phrase*. You would only expect the main noun to be pluralised.

So, 'factory closures' means multiple closures. And given that a single factory can't close more than once (at least not permanently), it must logically mean multiple factories. The same logic is why your example 2a is wrong.

Any valid single use of 'closure' must mean a single instance of a factory closing.

Comment: I am aware of a church that has closed more than once. Why can’t a factory?

Comment: @peter It must have reopened in between closures!! By that description, yes a factory (ie the building) could close more than once. But when you talk about 'closures', in most cases you would be talking about a spate of different businesses closing perhaps due to economic reasons. If one was able to reopen, either because it was bought out, or because financial conditions improved, that wouldn't really prove the rule and be part of the same wave of closures.

Answer (score 0):

Using a noun attributively as an adjective does not make the noun that comes after it plural, **ever**. To make the phrase plural, just add an s, like any other countable noun.

- door handle, door handles
- car door, car doors
- factory closure [is only for one factory; add s for the plural of more than one factory's closure: factory **closures**]

BUT, one can **always** write an attributive noun + noun in extended form if needed.

- The closures of a factory means *the factory was closed more than once*.
- The handles of the door means *the door had more than one handle*.
- The doors of the car means all the car doors.

You have to use your knowledge of things to see what makes sense.

Idiom: to go broke, past tense: went broke]

The owners of the factory went broke and each of its owners closed it: those would be called factory closures. Since the factory was closed twice.

Answer (score 0):

As others have noted, in the phrase "factory closure", "factory" is being used as an adjective to describe the type of closure, so we do not pluralize "factory".

So in general, "factory closure" is singular and means one closure of one factory. "Factory closures" is plural and means closures of many factories. (I think the issue of multiple closures of one factory is beside the point here so I'll just ignore it.)

That said, you could use the term in a general way. Like someone could say, "Factory closure is a common problem in the steel industry today." In that case you are speaking of the phenomenon in general, so you could be referring to just one instance, or, as here, to many instances.

Just like, "door handle" is singular. But if I said, "The door handle is a common feature on many residential home doors", I'm using it to refer to the idea in general and thus to many instances.

If someone used the singular without the context calling for this general sense, like if they said, "There was a factory closure in Chicago yesterday", I would take that to mean singular, one factory closed. If they wanted to say that many factories closed, they should say, "There were many factory closures in Chicago."